# Beginner question about e.Item.ItemIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net

There's this line of code inside of some repeater's ItemDataBound event that includes e.Item.ItemIndex..Now I get it that ItemIndex is the index of the item in the list..

What's "e" and "Item" here ? Actually I do have an idea. Just want to be more clear. Could someone please tell me in simple terms ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an instance of the [RepeaterItemEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemeventargs.aspx) class. For a better understand of databinding, see the article [Mastering ASP.NET DataBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Mastering_DataBinding.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

**e** is an instance of [RepeaterItemEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemeventargs.aspx) and **Item** is [RepeaterItemEventArgs.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritemeventargs.item.aspx)

Comment: It is a parameter that is passed into the called method.